# Redirecting stdout of a process

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am writing a toy version of SSH in C, so I need to redirect stdin, stdout and stderr of the server shell to the client shell (by using pipes and sockets). Right now I have redirected only stdout. If I send commands like ls, netstat, etc there are no problems, the client receives the right output.
But if I write a C program wich, for example, asks for an int n and prints the numbers between 1 and n, and call it through the client I get this behavior: the client doesn't receive the string with the request of n, but if I tape n on the server shell the client receives the request string and the numbers. 
I have tried the same thing leaving stdout on the server shell and in this case it works correctly. I have tried to use fflush, fsync and setvbuf without solve it.
Another strange behavior is: if I call through the client the program httrack without redirecting stdout, the server shell shows the normal wizard wich asks for project name, url, etc.
But If I redirect stdout the client doesn't receive the wizard output, instead it receives the httrack help page.

This is the code that performs redirection. As you can see I used both system and execlp call, but the behavior is the same.

```
pipe(pipefd);
    if(fork() > 0)
    {
        close(pipefd[1]);
        *_result = fdopen(pipefd[0], "r");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        close(pipefd[0]);
        close(1);
        dup(pipefd[1]);
        system(buf);
        //execlp(buf, buf, NULL);
        exit(0);
    }
```

EDIT:
After this I call this function that reads the stream associated to the read end of the pipe and puts it on the socket. The other parameters are used by AES and log file.
sock_send encrypt the buffer and write it to the socket through sock_write. sock_write(_wsock, NULL, 0) only signals the end of the output. Anyway as I have pointed out before, the output of commands like ls etc. is ok.

```
void write_result(int _wsock, aes_context *_enc_ctx, unsigned char *_iv, FILE *_result, char *_ip_addr)
{
    unsigned char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    char lstr[MAX_LOG_LEN];

    while(fgets(buf, BUF_SIZE * sizeof(char), _result) != NULL)
    {
        //li scrivo sulla socket
        if(sock_send(_wsock, _enc_ctx, buf, strlen(buf) + 1, _iv) == -1)
        {
            sprintf(lstr, WRITE_SOCK_ERR, _ip_addr);
            log_str(lstr);
            close_connection(_wsock, _ip_addr);
        }
    }
    sock_write(_wsock, NULL, 0);
    fclose(_result);
}
```

Comment: This is nowhere near enough code to figure out what you're up to. ssh is a lot more complicated than a pipe+fork+exec, even ignoring the whole "oh yeah, encryption" part.

Comment: You should consider reading a book teaching you the basics about Unix. [Stevens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programming_in_the_Unix_Environment) is always a good point to start.

Comment: In fact I have talked about toy version. Anyway this is a minimal part of the code, I though it was useless post code about diffie-hellman key exchange, AES, etc. since the problem is redirection and not SSH. Unluckily right now I have no such time to read a book or part of it. So I will be very pleased if someone can explain me what's wrong.

Comment: What's wrong is we don't know what the rest of your program does. The part you've shown doesn't have any errors that are apparent from viewing it in isolation. Post a complete program.

Comment: The basic "forward stdin/stdout over a socket" program is [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) so that may be a better model for what you're trying to do than ssh. Reducing the program before you ask your question is good, but you reduced it so much that there aren't any socket-related syscalls in it. That's too much.

Comment: Ok. I have posted more code.

Comment: After your close(1) and dup(pipefd[1]), shouldn't you also do "close(2)" and another dup? Stderr is file handle 2.